# Using ML.NET's CreatePredictionEngine with emitted types

Tags: c#, reflection.emit, ml.net

For a project I'm working on, I need to use [ML.NET](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/machinelearning-ai/ml-dotnet)'s [CreatePredictionEngine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.modeloperationscatalog.createpredictionengine?view=ml-dotnet) method with emitted types for `TSrc` and `TDst`. I'm emitting those with `System.Reflection.Emit`.

Here's how I'm creating my dynamic prediction engine :

```
dynamic dynamicPredictionEngine;
var genericPredictionMethod = mlContext.Model.GetType().GetMethod("CreatePredictionEngine", new[] { typeof(ITransformer), typeof(DataViewSchema) });
var predictionMethod = genericPredictionMethod.MakeGenericMethod(inputObject.GetType(), outputObject.GetType());
dynamicPredictionEngine = predictionMethod.Invoke(mlContext.Model, new object[] { TrainedModel, PredictionPipeline });
```

Here, `inputObject` and `outputObject` are instances of my emitted classes.

Then, I'm running the prediction engine like so :

```
var result = dynamicPredictionEngine.Predict(inputObject)
```

But I get the following Exception :

```
'The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.ML.PredictionEngineBase<Object0f33ea95-c496-4c57-bd2c-728bb65dd0a9,Object5623e4bd-ba82-42cf-876f-5e11a5cb8bb2>.Predict(Object0f33ea95-c496-4c57-bd2c-728bb65dd0a9)' has some invalid arguments'
```

The GUID you see here are the names of my emitted classes.

To debug this, I tried to manually create a class that has the same properties as the emitted one, and ran the prediction engine again, with the manually created class as `TSrc` and kept the emitted one as `TDst`. This time, it worked fine.

I looked at the debugger to compare the emitted input class with the manually created one, and they seem to match (`TaxiTrip` is the name of the class I created) :

[Debugger screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytHEN.png)

For reference, here's how my `TaxiTrip` class is defined

```
namespace VL.ML
{
    class TaxiTrip
    {
        public string VendorId { get; set; }
        public string RateCode { get; set; }
        public float PassengerCount { get; set; }
        public float TripTime { get; set; }
        public float TripDistance { get; set; }
        public string PaymentType { get; set; }
        public float FareAmount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea about what's going on here?

I already stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53837654/ml-net-makepredictionfunction-dynamic-type) on SO, but my issue looks different : as I said if I create a class manually without any attributes (see above), `Predict` works just fine. Plus, it seems to be able to make use of my emitted type for `TDst`, so why would `TSrc` fail?

Happy to provide more details if necessary.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just curious, any reason you're using reflection to make the call instead of using a prediction engine or prediction engine pool?

Comment: Take a look at my solution to a similar question.  I give sample code to using emitted code to create a PredictionEngine.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893993/ml-net-create-prediction-engine-using-dynamic-class/66913705#66913705

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to invoke the Predict method:

```
var predictMethod = dynamicPredictionEngine.GetType().GetMethod("Predict", new[] { runtimeType });
var predict = predictMethod.Invoke(dynamicPredictionEngine, new[] { inputObject });
```